# How can I send an escape sequence from a nested tmux session to iTerm2?

Tags: tmux, escape-characters, iterm2

This works (puts the date and time in the clipboard) in just iTerm:

`printf "\e]1337;Copy=:$(date | base64)\a"; echo $(pbpaste)`

This works in tmux running locally (using the DCS passthrough):

`printf "\ePtmux;\e\e]1337;Copy=:$(date | base64)\a\e\\"; echo $(pbpaste)`

This works in tmux running remotely:

`printf "\ePtmux;\e\e]1337;Copy=:$(date | base64)\a\e\\"; echo $(ssh -p 2222 -qt localhost pbpaste)`

My only problem is running tmux remotely under a local tmux:

`printf "\ePtmux;\e\ePtmux;\e\e]1337;Copy=:$(date | base64)\a\e\\\e\\"; echo $(ssh -p 2222 -qt localhost pbpaste)`

I think the problem is the inner `\e\\` is being interpreted as the outer `\e\\`.

Is there some way to escape the inner `\e\\` so it makes it the outer tmux properly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to double every \e for each tmux, including the \e in the terminating \e\\, so:

```
printf "\ePtmux;\e\ePtmux;\e\e]1337;Copy=:$(date | base64)\a\e\e\\\e\\"
```

Alternatively if you configure tmux to use OSC 52 and then turn it on in iTerm2 ("Applications in terminal may access clipboard" from a quick search) it will pass  through each tmux (creating a paste buffer in each) to the host clipboard. For tmux you will need something like:

```
set -as terminal-overrides ',tmux*:Ms=\\E]52;%p1%s;%p2%s\\007'
set -as terminal-overrides ',screen*:Ms=\\E]52;%p1%s;%p2%s\\007'
set -s set-clipboard on
```

Then you can do this in the innermost tmux:

```
printf "\033]52;$(date)\007"
```

Of course this will mean anything you copy in tmux will also go into the host clipboard which you may not want.

Comment: Setting up OSC 52 works great, thanks. But I wanted to send other escape sequences as well (for growl notifications and other stuff).  The printf is hanging, but that seems to be related to printf as `perl -e 'print "\ePtmux;\e\ePtmux;\e\e\e\e]1337;Copy=:@{[`date | base64`]}\n\a\e\e\\\e\\"'` is working.

Comment: Try piping both printf and perl to `cat -v` or `od` or something (eg `printf "..."|cat -v`) and compare what they are sending to tmux to see what printf is doing differently.

Comment: Thank you so much! Note that I had to use single backslashesi the `terminal-overrides` (so that `tmux show -s terminal-overrides` displays double backslashes instead of four...)

Comment: Also your OSC52 test command did not work for. That's probably on my terminal (mintty). I had to use `printf "\033]52;c;$(date | base64)\a"`.